# PowerShell - Copying files in random folders to other folders

Tags: powershell

I have the following text file (tab delimited) that maps a specific file to a folder. I start with importing this csv:

```
SourcePathFile  DestinationPath
C:\Test\Source\SourceDir 1\pic1.jpg C:\Test\Destination\Folder, 1
C:\Test\Source\SourceDir 1\Pic 2.jpg    C:\Test\Destination\Folder 2
```

By using:

```
Import-csv -Delimiter `t "C:\Test\FileMapping.csv"
```

This gives me the array I want, so I figured that it would be a simple For-each to go through each line using

```
Copy-Item SourcePathFile DestinationPath
```

I'm clearly missing the general concepts

Comment: If you post your actual code we can give you an actual answer, but essentially in your foreach loop there is some variable that is being assigned an object every iteration (probably $_). SourcePathFile and DestinationPath are properties of this variable so you would access them with something like $_.SourcePathFile and $_.DestinationPath.

Comment: `$CSV|%{([System.IO.FileInfo]$_.SourcePathFile).CopyTo((Join-Path $_.DestinationPath (Split-Path $_.SourcePathFile -Leaf)),$true)}` would do what you want assuming all your paths are accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your input file is valid [TSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values) (is comma at the end of the line `2` is intended?) you can do this using pipeline:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Test\FileMapping.csv' -Delimiter "`t" |
    ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.SourcePathFile -Destination $_.DestinationPath}
```